# Reduce Generated GIF Size Using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, gif

I'm developing android application that converts `mp4` files into `gifs` using `ffmpeg`.
Problem is that generated gifs are huge in size. And another problem is that I can't use anything else than `ffmpeg`(e.g.`imagemagick` for `convert`, or even `palletes` for now) to reduce generated gif size.

this is the command I'm using:
`ffmpeg -y -i file.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -s 320x480 file.gif`

So is there any other way to optimize conversion?

Comment: try `magick  out.gif -fuzz 30% -layers Optimize result.gif`

Comment: Why not use webp instead of gif. Webp can use more colores than gif and produces an animaed imagesequence with much lower size.

Comment: "Why not use webp instead?" Because support for webp is still exceedingly spotty.

Answer (score 26):

The standard way to use ffmpeg for GIFs is

**Generate a palette** from the video

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.mp4 -vf palettegen palette.png
```

Then,

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex paletteuse -r 10 -s 320x480 file.gif
```

More options documented [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#paletteuse).

Comment: Weirdly, generating a palette tripled the size of the GIF, although it greatly increased the quality over the default palette. I found the best way is to generate the GIF with ffmpeg as per usual (possibly with a better palette as in this answer) then just run it through an optimization tool (there's ones online too) that can make unchanging parts of the frame transparent or apply other optimizations.

Comment: TFW 5 years later, you've got a question, you find a useful answer, you read a helpful comment and think "ah yeah; I noticed that, too", and then you realize that comment was yours. 

Comment: Generating a palette worked really well for me for a screen capture: reduced the size by 25%. Then running through `gifsicle` reduced it again, with an overall reduction of 70%.

Answer (score 25):

Below command helped me optimising my gif's. The parameters can change based on your specific requirements.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "fps=5,scale=480:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=max_colors=32[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=dither=bayer" output.gif
```

Note:

- here ***scale*** and ***max_colors*** drastically impacts the output
  gif's filesize.
- If you set a low values for scale and max_colors, setting up
  ***dither*** to ***bayer*** makes the output gif look a little better. Default value for dither is ***sierra2_4a***

Comment: This is the one that finally worked for me. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 11):

I tried all these techniques and I ended up using https://ezgif.com

I have no idea what magic they're using under the hood, but their compression level knob, palette optimization and resolution reduction resulted in the highest visual quality and smallest file size.

I tried `-vf palettegen` and `-filter_complex paletteuse` but that removed the ability to `-vf "scale=iw*.2:ih*.2"` in the same run so I had to do that separately. And ffmpeg created larger files for `0.3` scale than `0.5` which is odd. After an hour of fiddling, I tried ezgif and it worked nicely.

Comment: you can just `-filter_complex "paletteuse,scale=iw*.2:ih*.2"` instead of `-vf`

Answer (score 6):

```
vid=       
start_time=00:00:01
duration=5       
height=ih/2      # input height halved , can replace with pixils . 
width=-2         # keeps aspect ratio . can replace with pixils . 
fps=25           # frames per a second .

filters="fps=$fps,scale=$width:$height:flags=lanczos"

ffmpeg -ss $start_time                             \
       -t  $duration                               \
       -i  "$vid"                                  \
       -vf "$filters,palettegen"                   \
       -y  palette.png                             &&
ffmpeg -ss $start_time                             \
       -t  $duration                               \
       -i  "$vid"                                  \
       -i  palette.png                                \
       -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse"  \
       -y  "$vid".gif                              &&
rm palette.png
```

[link to documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling)

[more info](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html)

Comment: Where is `$palette` being set in your script?

Comment: where the command is run

Comment: sorry .  there was a mistake with palette file .  fixed now .

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me  was specifying a lower frame rate than the 10 you're using (-r 10) for the output gif. Probably not what you want if you're after good quality. If you're after a better quality gif then it will be bigger in file size.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment to ubershmekel response, ezgif.com indicates that for their compression:

> GIF compressor optimizes GIFs using Gifsicle and
> [Lossy GIF](https://kornel.ski/lossygif) encoder, which implements lossy LZW
> compression.

I obtained similar sizes as with the ezgif "Lossy GIF compression" just doing

```
./gifsicle -O3 --lossy=35 -o lossy-compressed.gif input.gif
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1130083)